# Understanding だけ in this context: 『...ことでもなく。... いいだけじゃないか』

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> それはたしかに、言うとおりなのだが。自分だって彼以外の『エイティシックス』は──何しろ会ったこともないわけだし──得体が知れないし、ちょっと怖いなと思わなくもない。
>
> でも、そんな大仰に言う**ことでもなく**。普通に声をかけて、話をして、どういう奴なのかわかっていければ、**いいだけじゃないか**と思うのだけれど……。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

Why is the だけ used in the sentence? Can we just say いいじゃないか? How should I understand the だけ? And does the bold ことでもなく mean the same as ことはない, namely, "not necessary"? Or, literally, it is just "it’s not something to be exaggerated"?

Comment: Doesn't completely answer your questions, but this may help: [What does 言わなきゃいいだけ mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44201/)

Answer (score 1):

・・・ことはなく、・・・いいじゃないか works and means almost the same, but it adds somewhat the blaming tone. In simple terms, ことはない sounds *It is not something you should say in such a 大仰な way (but you do and I'm uncomfortable with it)* while でも  weakens the tone and sounds a bit softer. That said, semantically mostly the same with or without でも.

Similarly だけ adds 'no big deal' tone to いいじゃないか and both are not that different in meaning. It is kind of correlative with the previous でも. The sentence could be translated as *But you don't have to say in such a 大仰な manner. Instead you just have to...*

Comment: Thank you very much. I previously thought the だけ meant "only" and added the nuance "it is only good (but no bad aspects of doing those things)".

Comment: By the way, how do you tell that this ことでもなく doesn’t mean the same as ことではない, namely, "it’s not something to be exaggerated"?

Comment: @chinoalpha Re 1st point, it could be interpreted as *only*: You have only to... Re 2nd point, I think both are similar. The subject of 言う is *you*, so ことではない would mean *not something that you (should) exaggerate*. All these boil down to more or less the same thing, but only subtle nuances. ことではない may imply it is something else due to contrastive は, ことはない sounds *You shouldn't* or possibly *You'd better not*.